# how to prevent a draggaable div from leaving its parent tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i want to prevent a draggable div from leaving its parent element
here is my code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
     div{
      border: 1px solid black;
      width:100px;
      height: 100px;
     }
 div:hover{
  cursor:default;
     }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div>
    <div class="smiley" id="smiley"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
     dragElement(document.getElementById("smiley"));
 function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById("smiley")) {
    document.getElementById("smiley").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.getElementById("smiley").style.top = (document.getElementById("smiley").offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    document.getElementById("smiley").style.left = (document.getElementById("smiley").offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
    </script>
    </body>
     </html>
```

i am not sure if it would work in the snippet, but it works in my browser(firefox), all i just need is to prevent it from being dragged outside of its parent element 
By the way i dont't need to add the boolean attribute "draggable" because the javascript makes it draggable

Comment: You would need to add collision detection. Basically, determine the `left`, `top`, `width`, `height` of the parent and then during drag event check for collision with those. I would advise using jQuery UI library as it is built in. See More: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a really basic example that helps clarify my comment. Again, you will need to clean it and make it do what you want to do, yet you can see how you cna use the Mouse position or the item position to perform various collision detection. There are LOTS of article on this topic.

```css
.containment {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.containment:hover {
  cursor: default;
}

.containment>div {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="containment">
  <div class="smiley" id="smiley"></div>
</div>
<script>
  function dragElement(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var containment = true;
    var pos = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    if (el) {
      el.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      pos[2] = e.clientX;
      pos[3] = e.clientY;
      console.log(e.type, pos);
      document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
      document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      pos[0] = pos[2] - e.clientX;
      pos[1] = pos[3] - e.clientY;
      pos[2] = e.clientX;
      pos[3] = e.clientY;
      var cPos = {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        right: el.parentElement.offsetWidth,
        bottom: el.parentElement.offsetHeight
      };
      var ePos = {
        left: el.offsetLeft,
        top: el.offsetTop,
        right: el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth,
        bottom: el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight
      };
      if (containment) {
        if (ePos.left >= cPos.left && ePos.right <= cPos.right && ePos.top >= cPos.top && ePos.bottom <= cPos.bottom) {
          el.style.top = (el.offsetTop - pos[1]) + "px";
          el.style.left = (el.offsetLeft - pos[0]) + "px";
        }
      }
      console.log(e.type, cPos, ePos);
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
      document.onmouseup = null;
      document.onmousemove = null;
    }
  }

  dragElement("smiley");
</script>
```